# "It is a highly unusual form of melody, one that..." — what is the referent of "one"?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

> It is a highly unusual form of melody, one that occurs only in this composer's work

In the above sentence, what is the referent of the pronoun *one*? Is it *melody* or the entire prepositional phrase *form of melody*? Or, perhaps the referent is the subject of the sentence, *it*? I frequently hear the rule that the referent has to be the prior proximate noun.

Comment: You're misunderstanding/misquoting that "rule" about *"prior proximate noun"*. In this case, as Barrie says, *"one"* references the whole ***noun phrase*** preceding - which has already been equated to *"it"* anyway. So semantically speaking it's splitting hairs to choose between *"it"* and *"a highly unusual form of melody"*, but if you want to be grammatically precise it's the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that the referent was the entire noun phrase *a highly unusual form of melody*. The head word is *form* and it is postmodified by *of melody*. A paraphrase would be *a highly unusual melodic form*.